# Need count record with special condition

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this table in my database:

```
num     p3         Value1   p22
  
   1    Developer1  0       process
   2    Developer1  0       process
   3    programmer  0       process1
   4    programmer  0       process1
   5    programmer  30      process1
   6    programmer  20      process1
   7    programmer  10      process1
```

I need count Value1 to get the result that contain of 0 and the max value with group by Type.

I have tried to do this query:

```
SELECT p3,
       SUM(CASE WHEN p22 IS NOT NULL and p22 ='process1' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS process1,
       SUM(CASE WHEN p22 IS NOT NULL and p22 ='process' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS process
FROM add_patient
group by (p3)
```

The result is :

```
 p3          process1 process

   Developer    0       2
   programmer   5       0
```

But I need the result for (Programmer = 3  Not 5) because I want to count just: these result:

```
   3    programmer  0       process1
   4    programmer  0       process1
   5    programmer  30      process1
```

Comment: `WHEN p22 IS NOT NULL and p22 ='process1' THEN` can be simplified as `WHEN p22 ='process1' THEN`, since if it is process1 it's not null.

Comment: Why no Developer1 in the result?

Comment: Do you want to use a WHERE clause before the GROUP BY to filter out records to not include in the GROUP BY?

Comment: @ jarlh why no Developer1 in the result?Because the issue not in developer is in count programmer

Comment: Is there some logic to which records you count and don't count?  For example, you want at most the first 3 from any one group?  Or perhaps values 10 and 20 are always excluded?  Ignore values once they start decreasing?

Comment: @ Randy in Marin you want at most the first 3 from any one group? No not fixed it will be a dynamic query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
with data as (
    select *, max(value1) over (partition by p3) as maxp3
    from add_patient
)
SELECT p3,
       SUM(CASE WHEN p22 = 'process1' AND value1 IN (0, maxp3)
                THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS process1,
       SUM(CASE WHEN p22 = 'process'  AND value1 IN (0, maxp3)
                THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS process
FROM data
GROUP BY p3
```

Comment: I tested it but why it say : Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'THEN' !

Comment: @mandarin I've edited a few times. Originally it was missing a parenthesis though.

Comment: It say another error : 'data' is not a recognized GROUP BY option

Comment: @mandarinsoftware Works for me: https://rextester.com/TBXP50660

Comment: Perhaps you're missing a semicolon before the `with`.